# Programmatic Masonry / Space-FInding Layout in Actionscript

Tags: jquery, actionscript, geometry

Can anyone point me to a good Actionscript 3 class that handles "masonry" style layouts ala the [ted.com](http://www.ted.com) homepage?

Short of finished code, can anyone describe / summarize an efficient algorithm that handles this effect? Searches turn up arcane articles about kd-trees and other such stuff that's way over my head.

The [jQuery Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) plugin looks great, but I tried reverse engineering it without much success.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't do exactly what you want but it's somewhat in the way:

http://wonderfl.net/c/bW3T

http://wonderfl.net/c/iFpf

http://wonderfl.net/c/aXkO

having 3 or 4 fixed sizes for boxes will help for sure :)